# How to achieve this in .Net 4.0 Without async

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, .net-4.0

I am trying to achieve this in .net 4.0. But getting errors

public async Task SetInterval(Func evaluate, TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken token){

```
await Task.Delay(interval).ConfigureAwait(false);

var result = evaluate();

if(result != default(T)) return result;

if(token. IsCancellationRequested) return default(T);

result = await SetInterval(cb, interval, token);

return result;
```

}

This can be invoked as

var source = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
  SetInterval(() => {}, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), source.Token);

Comment: .NET 4.0 is no longer supported. The earliest supported version is 4.5.2. *Why* do you want to target 4.0?

Comment: Assuming you have a valid reason (why? supporting legacy Windows XP applications?) you should add the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) package to your application. It adds `async/await`, Task.Run etc to .NET 4.0

Comment: I have a old component, whose framework version cannot be updated now.

Comment: Are you sure it hasn't already been updated? 4.5 is a binary upgrade to 4.0. If you or the target machine have a supported version installed, it's *already* running on 4.5+. BTW TLS1.2 was added in 4.5. You 'll run into trouble if you try to connect to any service that requires TLS1.2 - even Github requires TLS1.2 now

Comment: Anyway, if you don't want to write a ton of code, use Microsoft.Bcl.Async

Comment: Component, which I mentioned is plugin inside a desktop product. So I can't do anything with that. I have to see the options available in 4.0

Comment: Well, *add Microsoft.Blc.Async*